# how to delete firestore data with firestore authentication in swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

my SessionAuth

```
func deleteUser() {
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("error deleting user authentication data \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("User authentication data deleted successfully")
                self.db.collection("users").document(uid).delete { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("error deleting firestore data \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        print("Firestore data deleting successfully.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my firebase auth successfully delete, but my data cant delete. its Missing or insufficient permissions.

so this is my firestore rules :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{document} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
    }
  }
}
```

i want delete my data on firestore match with documentid authentication

Comment: You’d need to delete the data before deleting the user. You’re doing the opposite.

Comment: That sounds like an answer @jnpdx! 